# Unity Custom Shader Cannot Update Property In Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and set some simple shader properties, but according to the Inspector, they aren't being set. I'm new to shaders, not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a MeshA that has been assigned MaterialA. The mesh itself is adjusted/generated via code, run through an Editor Script-added button.

The terrainMaterial I am changing in my code below, is a reference to the material ASSET, not this MeshA.

When playing the game, I also spawn (lets say 10) new Mesh Objects, all of which use MaterialA.

The code in game:

```
protected void UpdateMeshHeights()
{
    Debug.Log($"------------------------- Updating Mesh Heights ------------------------");
    //Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_minHeight", generationData.MinHeight);
    //Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_maxHeight", generationData.MaxHeight);
    terrainMaterial.SetFloat("_minHeight", generationData.MinHeight);
    terrainMaterial.SetFloat("_maxHeight", generationData.MaxHeight);
    Debug.Log($"Shader Min Height: {terrainMaterial.GetFloat("_minHeight")}"); // value correct
    Debug.Log($"Shader Max Height: {terrainMaterial.GetFloat("_maxHeight")}"); // value correct
}
```

The custom shader code:

```
Shader "Custom/TerrainShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _minHeight ("_minHeight", float) = 0.0
        _maxHeight ("_maxHeight", float) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        float _minHeight;
        float _maxHeight;

        struct Input
        {
            float3 worldPos;
        };

        float inverseLerp(float a, float b, float value)
        {
            return saturate((value-a)/(b - a));
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            float proportion = inverseLerp(_minHeight, _maxHeight, IN.worldPos.y);
            o.Albedo = proportion;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

So when reading the values, e.g. _maxHeight, it shows the value I expect. However, the properties on the material still say 0 (and the material is all white, per the inverse lerp calculation with values of 0 for both a and b).

I used global floats temporarily (without anything in Properties) to check the code is working, I see the shader doing exactly what I expect so the issue is definitely how I'm setting (or not setting rather) the properties.

EDIT: Added extra context

Comment: Okay so I'm still working on this, and basically doing some guess and check testing. If someone could clarify specifically the behaviour, that would be much appreciated, but this is what happens (and what is needed) using _maxHeight as an example-

    1) Editing the material's _maxHeight will change it for all objects created and assigned that material, but will NOT change anything for already existing objects with that material

    2) On the other hand, using the Shader.SetGlobalFloat will change EVERYTHING past and present because . . . it's global.

Comment: As an additional side note (and I have absolutely no idea why), if you DUPLICATE an object and change (one) object's .sharedMaterial _maxHeight, it will affect the duplicated object's shader too. HOWEVER it has no effect on non-duplicated (new) objects created and assigned that material. Taking a wild guess, there probably a difference between those two situations regarding the material referenced.

Comment: Final Comment - through Inspector's Debug option, you can see indeed that the CTRL+D command of Unity duplicated the object including the material reference itself, as both objects share the same ref ID. However, even assigning newObject.sharedMaterial = existingObject.sharedMaterial does not give the same refID, which is why once object is created it is no longer affected by changes to that existing object.

Comment: Well good guesses ;) indeed Unity uses material instantiating so that individual objects can have individual material modifications ... going through `sharedMaterial` as the name says is shared among instances of that object .. but only as long as they don't have any instanced material which happens as soon as you modify it on runtime